# Is it better to use RouterLink or router.push for a button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

I am using Vue Router 4 in Vue 3 Composition API, and I want to make a back button. I want to know what is the most optimal and good practice to redirect, a RouterLink or the router with the push method..

RouterLink

```
    <RouterLink :to="{ name: 'clients-index' }">
      <AppButton text="Volver" icons="fa-chevron-left" />
    </RouterLink>
```

router.push

```
    <AppButton text="Volver" icons="fa-chevron-left" @click="() => router.push({ name: 'clients' })" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly written inside the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) that ***clicking `<router-link :to="...">` is the equivalent of calling `router.push(...)`***.

In router-link we create anchor tags for declarative navigation and the same job can be done programmatically using the router's instance, `router.push`. To navigate to a different URL we use `router.push` and this is the same method called internally when you click a `<router-link>`.

| Declarative | Programmatic |
| --- | --- |
| `<router-link :to="...">` | `router.push(...)` |

So use either a declarative or programmatic approach, both are equalized.

Comment: There's a distinctive difference, router link provides a real link, which is good for UX most times